# Need to fetch dates from a mongodb document and use it to make a table in jsp

Tags: java, mongodb, jsp

***`I need to get the dates so that I can make a table out of it.`***

the below is the mongodb code snippet

```
{
    "sport" : "Basketball",
    "venue" : "Youth Arena",
    "date" : ["8-6-2016","8-7-2016","8-8-2016","8-9-2016","8-10-2016","8-11-2016","8-12-2016","8-13-2016","8-14-2016","8-15-2016","8-17-2016","8-18-2016","8-19-2016","8-20-2016"]
}
```

Comment: be more specific, it's not clear from your question what result do you expect and what have you already tried. it's also not clear how your issue relates to java and jsp.

Comment: I want to get dates seperately so that I can make a table with each date.

Comment: I am not able to get each date separately.

Comment: Ok, if you run a 'find' from java, you get this document. What prevents you from accessing the 'date' field and looping over it? If you're using the basic mongodb driver get a 'DBObject' on which you can run obj.get("date"). Have you tried this?

Comment: @PelitMamani : Yes I did that. but did not work for me, I need sport and date both. And somehow it's not working for me.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide us with a code snippet showing what you've tried and what the result was?